# why is my javascript not loading

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webview, cordova-3

I am using cordova 3.04 in my android app

this is my mainactivity code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CordovaInterface {

    CordovaWebView cwv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        cwv = (CordovaWebView) findViewById(R.id.cwv);
        Config.init(this);
        cwv.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        cwv.loadUrl("JavaScript:sayHelloFromJS('hi')");
    }
}
```

and html code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function sayHelloFromJS(value) {
                alert("JavaScript says: Hello asasasa !!! How are you?");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

i am loading the html page first then loading javascript why is it that html is loading fine and javascript isnt loading at all.

Comment: not familiar with Cordova, but have you tried `cwv.loadUrl("javascript:sayHelloFromJS('hi')");`?

Comment: yes i tried it in fact cwv.loadUrl("javascript:alert('hi')"); is working

Comment: I always used cordova with an activity that extends DroidGap, and a different class thats extends CordovaPlugin, but I assume that CordovaInterface is based on WebInterface then this is how I loaded the js webView.loadUrl("javascript:scrollTo("value")"); Note this is a webview.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
cwv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

`CordovaWebView` uses `java.lang.String.startsWith()` to check values passed to `loadUrl`, to decide how to "load" the URL. It's been this way in [the source](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView.java#L430) for a while.

`startsWith()` is **case-sensitive** so you want

```
cwv.loadUrl("javascript:sayHelloFromJS('hi')");
```

not

```
cwv.loadUrl("JavaScript:sayHelloFromJS('hi')");
```

... or you will get a protocol not supported error.

I don't know what you mean by "JavaScript is not loading", but if you are expecting an alert saying "hi" then your JS needs fixing, because `sayHelloFromJS` is ignoring the value passed to it ;)

```
    function sayHelloFromJS(value) {
        alert(value);
    }
```